# Can't able to see the custom parameter on Firebase console log

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I'm getting this warning **GoogleTagManager warning: Event does not have parameter “shopping_tool_origin” and no default value was defined. Returning “undefined”** on Xcode console log, even we sent this custom parameter "shopping_tool_origin" on this event "add_to_cart" to Firebase properly. And we have created tag for this event and its corresponding parameters on Google Tag Manager(GTM) also.

During development with debug build we can't able to see this param “shopping_tool_origin” details on Firebase console log. But we can able see the other custom parameters like “shopping_tool_detail & shopping_tool_label” on Firebase console log.

Im not sure why can't see that custom parameter on Firebase console log as well why we getting the warning messages from GTM ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As so far I got reason why can't able to see some parameters on Firebase debug view console.

Reason is since a Firebase update this issue appear more and more.

We have un-zoom debug view console page with Ctrl + "-" then we will be able to see everything however it will be really small...